# How to suppress EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000000915e3957 (Objective-C iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I got into a situation where the crash is in production app but not in debug application, so not able to reproduce the crash in debug application.I am getting the crash reports from Crashlytics

Here is the stack trace of the bug and it is something related to EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS which is painful to debug as generally people say

```
Crashed: command_dispatch
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000000915e3957
 Raw Text

#0  libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 5

#1  CoreFoundation  -[__NSArrayM removeAllObjects] + 182

#2  Almond  -[self removeObjectFromArray:]
```

Definition of removeObjectFromArray:

```
-(void)removeObjectFromArray:(NSMutableArray *)array{
   if(array!=nil && array.count>0){
      [array removeAllObjects];
    }
 }
```

The method removeObjectFromArray is called in the below method

```
-(void)cleanUp{
   [self removeObjectFromArray:self.array];
}
```

the parameter self.array is strong and atomic which are by default and property of this class(Let the name of this class be Main class).

The values to this property array is assigned in a method of another class as below

```
 -(void) fillData {
     NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray new];
     //fillArray fills the array created and assigns the array to the array in MainClass
     [self fillArray:array];
     MainClass.array = array;
 }
```

The crash is inside the method removeObjectFromArray because of accessing memory that is already released which I have learnt from other posts, to avoid that I am having a nil check before sending message to the array.

Does not the object be nil if the memory is released or is the memory released after code execution passing the nil check or should I lock the array object before nil check and unlock the object after nil check, or the array that is created and assigned to the array of this class might have released, did I miss any case or any suggestions how to suppress this bug stopping the app from crashing is appreciable.

Comment: please comment if you need more information

Comment: Instead of `MainClass.array = array` try to assign a explicit deep copy of `array` to `MainClass.array`

Comment: @Sharpkits can you please reason out how does that make a difference in your point of view, thanks for the reply

Comment: My guess is, the array in question is released, but reference to the memory it used to occupy is still stored in a variable. I think it might be useful to know in which context cleanUp is used. As a side note, there is no need to check if array is nil to call removeAllObjects – calls on nil are treated as "no-op".

Comment: cleanUp is called for some internal purposes(clearing the array) nothing related to app life cycle methods or memory warnings

Comment: It might be possible that `array` is release from memory but reference in `MainClass.array` is still there so making a deep copy could figure out the problem.

Comment: ARC or not?    There are a few code style issues here.   Doesn't necessarily cause problems, but indicates a general lack of understanding how the APIs work.  (-removeObjectFromArray: empties the array entirel?!)

Comment: @bbum Thanks for the reply, I am using ARC and removeObjectFromArray is supposed to remove the array contents for me, and the nil check before the removeAllObjects is to check if the array is nil to avoid crash, but i have purposefully made the array nil and sent removeAllObjects message which is not causing the crash, don't know the reason for my crash

Comment: ObjC is "nil eats message".  Messaging nil or an empty array will not cause a crash.   Your crash is because an object in the array has been corrupted or over-releaseed.  As you are using ARC, there is something tricky going on.